# Nav bar disappears after filling bowser window with div

Tags: html, css

Trying to center text within a div which spans the size of the browser window with a background image. Also would like the 'scroll button' text to remain near the bottom of the div. For some reason the ul used in the nav disappears when float is used. Have been looking around for a while now and can't seem to find anything to help figure it out.

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
#firstThing {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('bike.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#scroll {
  color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="whatev.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id='firstThing'>
    <div id='title'>
      <h2>Some Text</h2>
    </div>
    <p id='scroll'>Scroll Button</p>
  </div>
  Other Stuff
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For scroll button use `bottom: 0`, **not** `top: 95%`. Can't see anything vanishes in there, when does `ul` disappears?

Comment: ul disappears when li is set to float left

Comment: could u provide full example with your issue? currently we see the ul and it does not disappear.